# Java Reflection : internals of java.lang.reflect.Field.getDouble(object)

Tags: java, reflection, field

Does anyone know if Field.getDouble(Object) boxes and unboxes a double internally?

Thanks,
RB

Answer (score 1):

If you use Field.getDouble() on a `double` field, there is no auto boxing/unboxing.  This method existed long before this was available.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Sun/Oracle Reflection API tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTrouble.html):

> When using reflection, type checking only occurs at runtime so there
>   is no opportunity to box the value. ...To eliminate this exception,
>   the problematic line should be replaced by the following invocation of
>   Field.set(Object obj, Object value):  f.set(ft, new Integer(43));